# Macro to pull data from unnamed worksheets

Tags: excel, excel-2013, vba

Thank you in advance for the help with this question. I have a set of workbooks who have varying numbers of worksheets. On each worksheet, there are 6 cells of information that I need to have compiled onto one master worksheet in that workbook. The 6 cells of information are on the same page of every worksheet. My final output would be a table on one worksheet that has all of the data from the other worksheets in that book. I can do it manually but was hoping that a macro would help. I've tried using the activeworkbook.worksheet identifier but am stuck. Thanks for any help.

Comment: If you can do it manually, try using the macro recorder. Then come back when you have a specific question on the code that you have.

Comment: Revise your question to include some of your specifics, like sheet names and specific ranges. Definitely take @TheEngineer up on recording a macro, for a chunk of it, preferably if it's something you repeat, one full iteration of it. Then there's a frame of reference.  Otherwise all anyone can do is guess what you want to happen.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Just so you understand my text isn't meant to be harsh.  I'm just trying to help you get what you need, and learn from it in the process, while still fitting into the site's guidelines.  [See some examples here:](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: If you have tried using the ActiveWorkbook.WorkSheet identifier, that implies to me you have already tried some code. Please can you provide the code you have tried? It doesn't matter that it didn't work (after all, you wouldn't be here if it did), it will give us a better idea what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

I was going to suggest the same thing @TheEngineer did because your question sounded too general and the only answer seemed to be for someone to code a complete solution for you.

However, reading a little closer, I *think* what you are asking for is the loop I've given you below.

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
'
    ' 6 "working variables" to temporarily hold the values from each worksheet
    Dim sCell1 as String
    Dim sCell2 as String
    Dim sCell3 as String
    Dim sCell4 as String
    Dim sCell5 as String
    Dim sCell6 as String

    Dim iTargetRowIdx as Integer 'counter to point at next empty row in target sheet
    iTargetRowIdx = 1 'NOTE: change this if your 1st target row is not 1

    For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

        'avoid copying from the target worksheet itself
        If Sheet.Name <> "<your target sheet name>" Then

            'copy value from each of 6 cells to our working variables
            'INSTRUCTION: replace each pair of "<row>" and "<col>" with row and column numbers of each of your 6 cells
            sCell1 = Sheet.Cells(<row>, <col>) ' 1st cell to copy
            sCell2 = Sheet.Cells(<row>, <col>) ' 2nd cell to copy
            sCell3 = Sheet.Cells(<row>, <col>) ' 3rd cell to copy
            sCell4 = Sheet.Cells(<row>, <col>) ' 4th cell to copy
            sCell5 = Sheet.Cells(<row>, <col>) ' 5th cell to copy
            sCell6 = Sheet.Cells(<row>, <col>) ' 6th cell to copy

            'NOTE: if you want to see the value of what's in a cell while the macro is running, you can use Debug.Print, which prints to your Immediate Window (the little panel) at the bottom of the VBA editor) e.g.
            Debug.Print (Sheet.Cells(1, 1))
            'this prints what is in cell A1
            'NOTE: Debug.Print is just a debugging tool to help you see what is going on inside your macro - you can safely remove the statement altogether
        End If

        'then put code here to paste those values to the next row in your target worksheet
        'assumes you want the 6 values pasted to cols A to F in each new row
        Worksheets("<your target sheet name").Cells(iTargetRowIdx, 1) = sCell1
        Worksheets("<your target sheet name").Cells(iTargetRowIdx, 2) = sCell2
        Worksheets("<your target sheet name").Cells(iTargetRowIdx, 3) = sCell3
        Worksheets("<your target sheet name").Cells(iTargetRowIdx, 4) = sCell4
        Worksheets("<your target sheet name").Cells(iTargetRowIdx, 5) = sCell5
        Worksheets("<your target sheet name").Cells(iTargetRowIdx, 6) = sCell6

        iTargetRowIdx = iTargetRowIdx + 1 'point to next empty row
    Next Sheet
End Sub
```

This loops through every sheet in your workbook.  Inside the loop, you do all the work you described. You need to edit the code for your specifics.

You didn't say if you want to run one macro for ALL workbooks or if just on one workbook. This macro runs for only one workbook and that is the workbook where you place this macro. You can put this macro in every workbook that you want it to work in OR you can post a separate question about how to run one macro on many workbooks.

Comment: _"I was going to suggest the same thing @TheEngineer did because your question sounded too general"_ Then it probably is too broad and should be voted down and flagged, not answered...

Comment: Well, I believe we should answer if we can help. Everyone said he should just Macro Recorder. However, the question is "Excel macro to pull from unnamed worksheets" and further clarified by "I've tried using the activeworkbook.worksheet identifier but am stuck". This clearly tells that he was having trouble with general references to the sheets in his active workbook. These specifics were clouded by all the other information he provided, which I realised after reading more carefully.

Comment: Nice work.  That's as complete of an answer as a question such as this can get.